# No gas shutoff valve… trying to replace cooktop safely

Tags: plumbing, gas, appliances, natural-gas, cooktops

[image]

Hey all! I’m trying to do this right and hoping you folks can help me along. I got a new gas cooktop and need to change them out. While I enjoy doing as much DIY stuff as possible on my own, I’ve seen enough caution on this topic (especially related to how shutting gas off for the whole house ends up impacting all my other gas appliances needing to be checked as part of this simple job), that I’ve called in a plumber to help with this on Monday.

Here’s my question: Is there a safe way for me to trash my old existing cooktop before the plumber arrives on Monday?

Ideally, I could rip my old one out of the wall, cap off the gas line at this location, use the new clean area to easily cut the rough openings larger as required for the new cooktop without any wiring or hosing in the way, and then even set the new cooktop in place so that all of that is ready before the plumber arrives Monday. They will be here to “do plumbing,” not “install appliances.”

The issue I see, though, is I don’t see a way to do this without shutting off gas to the whole house. Can I shut off the house’s gas, disconnect this whole system from the supply line in the cabinet, just screw on a temporary cap, and then turn the gas to the house back on? Or is even this simply procedure something to be concerned about with how it can impact my other gas appliances throughout the house (water heater, 2 air handlers, and a fireplace)?

I understand that maybe the right thing to do it just leave everything as is and wait for the plumber/gas fitter to do his thing… but I’m also trying to avoid him showing up feeling like I didn’t prep enough of the new appliance which should be my burden.

By the way, I’ve also requested that they come ready to install a new ball valve inside this cabinet so that I have an easy access gas disconnect at the cooktop from now on.

Thanks in advance y’all!

Comment: since you already wisely requested a professional help, leave it alone.

Comment: Shutoff might be "remote", as in the basement below, in an adjacent cabinet, behind an access panel, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave it alone and let the pros handle everything. You've already told them you want them to install a gas shutoff so they know they have to disconnect some sort of fitting so they can add the valve. Some areas do not allow regular home owners to mess with gas connections so if that's the case, more reason to leave it for the pros.
If you're allowed to do it, get the right cap or valve, shut off the gas at the main valve and install your fitting and turn the main back on. Check for leaks. The other appliances should not be affected if you do this fast.

Comment: Strongly agree. There’s a risk of loosening hidden connections while messing around with a cap.

Comment: Thanks guys! I just spent the weekend enlarging the rough-in hole to fit the new cooktop. Everything else left untouched, ready for the plumber for tomorrow morning. I appreciate y’all’s wisdom and guidance 

Answer (score 1):

You can shut off the gas to the whole house without harming appliances.  Then, remove the flex (and adapter to pipe if it has one), clean the pipe threads off, and cap the pipe.  Seal the threads with pipe dope or yellow teflon tape (it's the kind for sealing flammable gas joints). Then you can turn the gas back on and check for leaks using soapy water - if it bubbles, shut off the gas, take apart, clean the threads, and reassemble the parts.  Then relight pilots, if any - most modern appliances have electric glow bars or arc starters instead of pilot lights.